# Which words have historically had a final n only before a vowel?

Tags: etymology, phonology, historical-change, determiners, vowels

In Modern English, the only word that has a final *n* only before a vowel is *a*/*an*:

> a face
>
> an eye

In Middle English, there was the pair *my*/*mine*:

> my face
>
> mine eye

Also, *the* was *then* before a vowel. What these words have in common (apart from changing pronunciation depending on the following sound) is that they are determiners. As such there should be a finite number of them.

Which words in the history of English have had two forms, one before consonants and one before vowels?

Comment: I haven’t seen “then” as a variant of “the”. Was it used as often as the others?

Comment: You don't mean thy/thine?

Comment: In non-rhotic dialects words with terminal /r/ exhibit this variation. ... I think you'll find that the *-n* forms of *th-* are Old English inflectional endings which collapsed into *the*, although [*OED 1* s.v. **The, III.9.** ] says that "the neuter *đat*,*đet* remained longer before a vowel".

Comment: @Juhasz Yes, _thy_ / _thine_ would be another example, but hopefully someone can produce a complete list, not just more isolated examples.

Comment: Even Early Modern English had *mine/thine* before a word starting with a vowel sound. *"To thine own self be true"; "Weep O mine eyes and cease not"; "Lift thine eyes, O lift thine eyes to the mountains, whence cometh help"; "Mine eyes have seen the glory of the coming of the Lord".* Plus here's a twofer in this medieval Christmas carol, although not because they precede vowel sounds: *‘Nova, nova, Ave fit ex Eva. /
"It is not yet six weeks **agone** / 
Sin Elizabeth conceived John /
As it was prophesied **beforn."** /
Nova, nova.’* Now we would just say *ago* not *agone*.

Comment: @tchrist potentially forced into an unnaturally archaic form to meet the rhyme